# Deleting a record from database and Single Choice Item list in AlertDialog using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm kind of stuck on this portion of my codes.. Okay here's what I am trying to do:

- Delete a record inside the SQL lite database
- Delete the record also inside the AlertDialog Single Choice Item list

I think I did the right thing on revealing what's inside the database so that the records will appear inside the AlertDialog Single Choice list. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem.

```
    String getPlayer=""; //to be used later to store Player's name

public void revealWhenButtonRemove(){
    AlertDialog.Builder revealListOfNames = new AlertDialog.Builder(userProfile.this);
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM player", null);
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        ar.add(c.getString(0)+"\n"); //add to arrayList
    }
    Object[] objRevAr=ar.toArray();
   final String[] revAr= Arrays.copyOf(objRevAr, objRevAr.length, String[].class); // put into array revAr to display on List

    if(revAr.length == 0)
    { // if there is no saved Player Data
        revealListOfNames.setTitle("Awww.. :(");
        revealListOfNames.setMessage("No one is here yet");
        revealListOfNames.setNeutralButton("Oh, Okay..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel(); // Just cancel this dialog
            }
        });
    }
    else
    { // if there are players / is a player
        revealListOfNames.setTitle("Hmm.. which one to remove?");
        revealListOfNames.setSingleChoiceItems(revAr, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getPlayer = revAr[which].toString(); //save selected Player name to getPlayer variable for assessment later
            }
        });
        revealListOfNames.setPositiveButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { //if user chooses to remove a player on the list
                    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM player WHERE playerName='" + getPlayer + "'"); //Line of code to delete record with the same name as with variable getPlayer

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aww.. " +getPlayer+" has been removed :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        revealListOfNames.setNegativeButton("Nah..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { //if user chooses to cancel dialog
                dialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uh.. Okay! :)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = revealListOfNames.create();
    // show alert
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**UPDATE (10/27/15):**

Never mind. I have already solved this on my end.. The line of code I missed was  `getPlayer = revAr[which].trim();`

This thread has been solved now!

Comment: The problem is `revAr.length == 0`?

Comment: how did it become a problem? What should I change here?

Comment: I mean what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I can't delete a record inside the database